# Installed Precise on XP SP3 machine in a separate partition, on Reboot system boots directly to XP, Why? How do I fix this?

Tags: dual-boot

All other questions don't seem to facing the exact same issue I am (or I haven't worded it properly). Like the title says: I have an XP SP3 system, I wanted to Dual boot into Ubuntu when needed. Ubuntu is installed on a separate harddisk and partition than XP - I can't get the menu to let me choose which OS to boot into. Any help?

Comment: try here --- http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-restore-grub-2-after-reinstalling-windows-xpvistawin7 --- has a specific thing for xp users.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to change the boot order in your bios menu. If you installed the Ubuntu bootloader on the second HDD and your computer boots from the first partition , first, it will come across Windows before it comes across the bootloader, meaning it will not give you the opportunity to choose. You should set it to boot from your second HDD first, which should lead you to the bootloader, which will give you your choice of OS. (Next time set the boot to your primary partition(: )